# Are there any recorded cases of two composers working independently composing the same thing?

Tags: composition

I heard the Miley Cyrus song **Party in the U.S.A.** on the radio yesterday (never heard it before) and I heard a vocal phrase that sounded very familiar. I couldn't place it for a while, but then it came to me - it sounds like a phrase from Sigrid's **Strangers**.

Are there any acknowledged cases of two composers working independently composing the same thing? Or is it more likely that Sigrid heard and quoted the Miley song without realising it?

[Miley Cyrus - Party in the U.S.A. (2009)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M11SvDtPBhA&t=60s&ab_channel=HollywoodRecordsVEVO)

[Sigrid - Strangers (2017)](https://youtu.be/cIriwVhRPVA?t=50)

Comment: On such stands a myriad court cases… Research George Harrison's My Sweet Lord for an early such case.

Comment: @Tetsujin - in the My Sweet Lord case, "…Harrison was found to have subconsciously plagiarised the song". I wondered whether any cases exist where it was decided *no* plagiarism had taken place, even though two songs sounded very similar.

Comment: …& it is the jury who has to make that call every single time someone brings yet another to court. There must be hundreds of similar cases.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_subject_to_plagiarism_disputes

Comment: I had a student who could find the beginning/end to '3 Blind Mice' somewhere  in just about every piece she played. Would that be admissible?

Comment: This is off topic, so just a comment. Two problems: the notion of independence, and sameness. Two internet streamed pop songs 8 years apart, the first one was a hit. How could anyone make a plausible claim of independent creation for the 2017 song? The 'sameness' of what you queued up is just a three beat hook. Probably not litigable, artistically could be called a quote.

Comment: @Tim was your student's name "Schenker" by any chance?  Or "Henrietta"?

Comment: @phoog - how did you guess? No, about 20 yrs ago, lost in the mists of something...

Comment: "I wondered whether any cases exist where it was decided no plagiarism had taken place, even though two songs sounded very similar." —well, since that comment, Ed Sheeran's case had that outcome.